# How to make a good HSE06 bandstructure for TMDC monolayer material (e.g.: WS2) in terms of VASP calculation INPUTS?

Tags: density-functional-theory, vasp, band-structure, hse06

I want to perform `HSE06 band-structure` calculation of a `WS2 monolayer`which has the following POSCAR with `17Ang` vacuum:

```
 W2S4                                   
   1.00000000000000     
     3.1912863255000001    0.0000000000000000    0.0000000000000000
    -1.5956425563000001    2.7637348281000000    0.0000000000000000
     0.0000000000000000    0.0000000000000000   20.1269199999999984
   W    S 
     1     2
Direct
  0.6666670084824631  0.3333329922369330  0.5000000000000000
  0.3333330949386806  0.6666670699615054  0.4218851941843354
  0.3333330949386806  0.6666670699615054  0.5781148058156645
 
  0.00000000E+00  0.00000000E+00  0.00000000E+00
  0.00000000E+00  0.00000000E+00  0.00000000E+00
  0.00000000E+00  0.00000000E+00  0.00000000E+00
```

**How I can make a good VASP input files for HSE06 bandstructure calculation?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I. self-consistent at PBE level. [1scf]

II. band calculation based on previous converged charge density. [2band]

III. HSE self-consistent calculation based on PBE self-consistent wavefunction. [3HSE_scf]

```
===HSE06 related tags in scf cal.

 LHFCALC = .TRUE.               !select the HSE06 hybrid functional

 HFSCREEN = 0.2

 ALGO = Damped

 TIME = 0.4

====
```

IV. HSE band calculation based on previous HSE self-consistent wavefunction.

(a) mv `IBZKPT` `KPOINTS`

(b) add k-points in reciprocal space from `OUTCAR` in band calculations to `KPOINTS` with zero weights.

```
===HSE06 related tags in band cal.

 LHFCALC = .TRUE.               !select the HSE06 hybrid functional

 HFSCREEN = 0.2

 ALGO = Normal

 TIME = 0.4

====
```

V. Plot band with `EIGENVAL` by excluding k-points with nonzero weight.

Comment: For step n°3 : Will I only need CHGCAR file from step n°1? Or I need also the WAVECAR file?. Also, I think the ICHGCAR=11 tag should be added for steps 2, 3 and 4, is that right ?

Comment: Read WAVECAR.  When the WAVECAR file was read successfully, the initial charge from the wavefunction.

Answer (score 7):

First you need a proper self-consistent calculation. Then you will need the previous wavefunction for HSE self-consistent calculations, and set the related parameter with ALGO = All/Damped. Then calculate the band structure with ALGO = Normal. Have a look at the manual and there are plenty of example in VASPWiki I believe.

Comment: You mean I run SCF-PBE. Then, use its WAVECAR for HSE06-SCF with ALGO = All/Damped. After that, I calculate HSE06 bandstructure with ALGO = Normal ? Could you please give me more details?